# Is the domain of $x$ stated for these formulae on the Wikipedia page correct?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> In the Wikipedia page
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions it is
> mentioned for the formulae shown in the image([click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions)) that
> the value of $x$ must be between $0$ and $1$.But how is that
> possible?
>
> $\sec^{-1}(x)$ and $\csc^{-1}(x)$ are not even defined in
> that region.

### My doubts:

- Is the assumption that $0<x<1$ wrong for the formulae?
- If yes, what is the correct domain of $x$ for validity of all the formulae?I suppose that just $x>0$ will suffice provided that it is within the domain of the individual function being dealt with.

---

P.S:Just adding a miniature screenshot of that part of the Wikipedia page, so that viewers can locate the formulae written on that page faster.(*Click On The Image To Expand*)

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is clearly a mistake. To begin with, the formulas also work for negative $x$ (in the appropriate range) as well. And for the formulas involving $\sqrt{x^2-1}$, the condition is $|x|>1$. Feel free to fix it!

Comment: @HansLundmark You say that will work for negative $x$ also.But say for $\tan(\sec^{-1}(-2))$ the formula doesn't work.What should be the correction?

Comment: Well, I didn't check all the formulas, but for example $\sin(\arcsin x))=x$ holds for $-1\le x \le 1$. For the formula that you mention, can't you just include a factor $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$? See the note in the section “Principal values” just above the image.